# Capistrano deploy error: 'ERROR: ld.so: object'

Tags: debian, capistrano

I get the following error when i try to deploy my RoR website to my remote server:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/var/www/vhosts/***/.vim_l' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

Im deploying my website with Capistrano on Debian 6.

Comment: Are you on a managed server like digital ocean? Did you create the user without going through Cpanel?

Comment: It's my own VPS and i dont' have Cpanel installed, the strange thing is deploying was working 2 days ago. I didn't change any configuration on the server and I got this error since yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably been infected by this botnet: http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/05/critical-ruby-on-rails-bug-exploited-in-wild-hacked-servers-join-botnet/

Check your crontab to be sure.